# C# object to list c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, listobject

I am reading in a csv file that I would like to add the second column into the same list as a column that match the name. I check the the next line is equal to the previous record but then I loop the array finding the match but I am not sure how to add that  internalList back into the class object.

> is there a better way to do this?

Program

```
while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
string[] words = s.Split('\t');

if (previousrecord == words[0])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ALEComName.Count; ++i)
        {

        }
}
else
{
    Name person = new Name();
    person.Name = words[0];
    List<SubName> internalList = new List<SubName>();
    SubName AssociatedSub = new SubName { Name = words[1] };
    internalList.Add(AssociatedSub);
    person.AssociatedSub = internalList;
    ALEComName.Add(Disease);
}
previousrecord = words[0];
```

Dto

```
    public class Name
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<SubName> AssociatedSub { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubName
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

CSV File

```
A   A
B   B
C   A
C   B
C   C
D   A
D   B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all lines, then use Linq:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\sample.txt");
var names = data.Select(d => d.Split('\t'))
.Select(s => new { Name = s[0], SubName = s[1] })
.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
.Select(g => new Name()
{
    Name1 = g.Key,
    AssociatedSub = g.Select(v => new SubName() { Name = v.SubName }).ToList()
});

//This part is just to show the output
foreach (var name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name.Name1}, AssociatedSub: {string.Join(",", name.AssociatedSub.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray())}");
}
```

Output:

> Name: A, AssociatedSub: A
>
> Name: B, AssociatedSub: B
>
> Name: C, AssociatedSub: A,B,C
>
> Name: D, AssociatedSub: A,B

I had to change the name of the property to `Name1` since it's an invalid language construct.

You first select the result of the split, then create an anonymous type with `Name` and `SubName` properties that will be used for grouping. Lastly, you select from the grouped results and create the instances.

This is just a quick sample so be careful for errors such as the `Split` not returning the expected numbers of parts.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq approach is very nice, I agree with the idea. I made a dictionary approach in case you wanted a more conservative way, which stores key,value pairs.

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            using(var file = new StreamReader(@"../file.csv")) {
                var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
                List<string> split;
                string line, key;

                while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    split = line.Select(l => new string(l, 1)).Where(l => l != " ").ToList();
                    key   = split[0];
                    split.RemoveAt(0);

                    if(dict.ContainsKey(key)) { 
                        dict.TryGetValue(key, out var values);
                        values.AddRange(split);
                    } else dict.Add(key, split);
                }

                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> r in dict) {
                    foreach(var val in r.Value) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Main = {0}, Sub = {1}", r.Key, val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```